# angular highlight searched text

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am using AngularJS for a search functionality and created a custom filter to highlight the searched text inside the results.

Below is my filter (JS):

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []).filter('highlight', function($sce) {
    return function(query, phrase) {
      if (phrase) query = query.replace(new RegExp('('+phrase+')', 'gi'),
        '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>')

      return $sce.trustAsHtml(query)
    }
});
```

And the related HTML:

```
<input ng-model="query" ng-keyup="search()" type="text" data-ele="home_search" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="">
<div ng-if="item.search_type == 'playset'" ng-animate="'animate'" ng-repeat="item in artists | filter: query | highlight:query" class="block gry-block">
```

After adding the filter, errors will appear and I don't know the reason.

Any help is appriciated.

You can also check this behavior at [this URL](http://engagev2.ncryptedprojects.com/).

Comment: What kind of errors it shows?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined. but you can look at the console in that like.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `angular-sanatize.js` file to return the inline style from the controller?

I wrote a non-regex solution to your problem. Not exactly an answer to your issue but feel free to use this [Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/bammmmmmmmm/pen/mMavEo).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: *angular-sanitize

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input id="searchText" type="search" placeholder="Search Asset..." ng-model="searchText" />
 <div ng-repeat="singleItem in yourArray| filter : searchText">
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you've provided isn't enough for me to give you a working example with your code. However, I'm assuming you want to highlight a keyword inside a DOM element. Then have a look at [mark.js](https://markjs.io/), a keyword/search term or custom regular expression highlighter.

Example:

```js
var markInstance = new Mark(document.querySelector(".context"));
function highlight(){
    var searchTerm = document.querySelector("input").value;
    markInstance.unmark().mark(searchTerm);
}
```

```css
mark{
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/julmot/mark.js/6.1.0/dist/mark.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Lorem ipsum..." oninput="highlight()">
<p class="context">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
```

Comment: Yes it can be done with this but as i want to learn that using angular

Comment: @AshishJoshi you can of course put this into a AngularJS function container, e.g. a directive.

Comment: @AshishJoshi Also, you could always open a feature request [here](https://github.com/julmot/mark.js/issues/new), describing your use case and a built-in solution might be implemented soon.